# Shrinking the JPanel in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a login page but unfortunately my formPanel's border is so out of bounds. Here in the pic you can see the titled border is way out. I need it to be more around my panel with login form:
[image]

I see that when creating this formPanel it is that big and the border just surround it. I tried with setPrefferedSize but its not working. How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
private JLabel title;

public LoginPanel() {
    this.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 43));
    this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //adding the title
    title = new JLabel("<html><h1><strong><i>Krisko Beatz Quiz</i></strong></h1><hr></html>");
    title.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
    titlePanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 43));
    titlePanel.add(title);
    this.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    //creating the login form
    JPanel formPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    formPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 43));

    //gbc
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();


    //gbc for username
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0);

    JLabel username = new JLabel("Username: ");
    username.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    formPanel.add(username, gbc);

    //gbc for textfield
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;

    JTextField usernameField = new JTextField(10);
    formPanel.add(usernameField, gbc);

    //gbc for pass
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;

    JLabel password = new JLabel("Password: ");
    password.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    formPanel.add(password, gbc);

    //gbc for pass field
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;

    JPasswordField passField = new JPasswordField(10);
    formPanel.add(passField, gbc);

    //gbc for button
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;

    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    formPanel.add(loginButton, gbc);


    //add border to the form panel
    TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Login");
    formPanel.setBorder(title);

    this.add(formPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). The problem is likely in code not included here. E.G. [this is how it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APIon.png) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried with setPrefferedSize but its not working.

Don't try to manage the preferredSize of a component.

I would guess the problem is that you are using `setSize(...)` instead of `pack()`.

You should be using `pack()` AFTER all the components have been added to the frame. Then all the components will be displayed at their preferred size.

Edit:

I originally misread your question and changed my original answer. The point in my original answer of using the "wrapper" panel is to give extra space to the wrapper panel, while keeping the "formPanel" at a fixed size. This way the titled border will remain around the formPanel even as the frame size is changed.

So again the basic approach for this type of solution is:

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
wrapper.add(formPanel, new GridBagConstraints());
this.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//this.add(formPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Can this form panel act like a wrapper panel. Because adding all my labels and textfields in formPanel and then adding formPanel to wrapper and finally adding wrapper to this doesnt seem logically to me. In your words i need an extra panel besides the formpanel and `this`

Comment: @j.DOE `this doesnt seem logically to me` its logical when you understand the concept of using different layouts on nested panels to achieve your desired layout. Added back in original suggestion with hopefully a better explanation. Again, my new answer may be more approapriate then the original answer. You still haven't posted your `MCVE/SSCCE` so we don't know exactly what you are doing or what you problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I took your `LoginPanel` class as is, and wrote a `Main` class around it to start the GUI.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new LoginPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Especially note, I did no explicit setting of the size, only a `pack()` call which resizes everything to its preferred size according to your layout.

The resulting layout looks perfectly fine to me.
[image]

So the conclusion is: Your `LoginPanel` is fine, but probably there is something wrong in your other code which you didn't post here.